# tkinter and configparser : looking for a more beautiful solution

Tags: python, tkinter, configparser

I want to use `config.ini`'s values as startup values for Tkinter Entry items.
When the program is finished, I want to write the content of these Entry into the `config.ini`.
I have 2 problems with the following code :

```
# create the Entry textboxes
e1 = Entry(f1); e1.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)
e2 = Entry(f1); e2.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
e3 = Entry(f1); e3.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W)

# fill them with content from config.ini file
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
e1.insert(0, config.get('Default','Param1'))
e2.insert(0, config.get('Default','Blah7'))
e3.insert(0, config.get('Default','Param3'))

tk.mainloop()

# save the Entry values to config.ini
config.set('Default', 'Param1', e1.get())
config.set('Default', 'Blah7', e2.get())
config.set('Default', 'Param3', e3.get())
config.write(open('config.ini','w'))
```

- First problem : once the `tk.mainloop()` is finished, `e1.get()` doesn't work anymore!
- Second problem : it's not so beautiful to have to *repeat* the same things 2 times in the code (once for reading, once for writing). Maybe there's a way to link the Entry with the `config.ini` parameters in a shorter way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Program and all widgets exist as long as `mainloop` is working - not only in `tkinter` but also in `wxpython`, `pygame`, etc. When `mainloop` is finishing work it destroys all widgets and window. You have to save config before mainloop.

You can add button `quit` with assinged function which first saves config and later closes program.

(not tested code)

```
def saveConfig():
    global config

    config.set('Default', 'Param1', e1.get())
    config.set('Default', 'Blah7', e2.get())
    config.set('Default', 'Param3', e3.get())
    config.write(open('config.ini','w'))

    root.quit()

Button(root, "QUIT", command=saveConfig)
```

Maybe you could also assing this function to `closing event` to save config when user uses close button `[X]`.

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", saveConfig)
```

---

Code for reading config and code for writing config are not identical. There is no shorter way.

You can only use lists and `for`-loop to make load/save "nicer" :)

```
 entries = []
 options = []

 entries.append(Entry(f1)); entries[-1].grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)
 options.append("Param1")

 entries.append(Entry(f1)); entries[-1].grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
 options.append("Blah7")

 entries.append(Entry(f1)); entries[-1].grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W)
 options.append("Param3")

 # load

 import ConfigParser
 config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
 config.read('config.ini')

 for index, e in enumerate(entries):
     e.insert(0, config.get("Default", options[index]) )

 # save

 for index, e in enumerate(entries):
     config.set("Default", options[index], e.get())

 config.write(open('config.ini','w'))
```